# Substring can't find what it should find

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string (replacedLigning) containing y=3-2+4x-6. I want xVærdi (an ArrayList) to contain the x value. In the example y=3-2+4x-6 I want the xVærdi to store "4", since that's how many x'es there are. The initial value of xVærdi is none, and the problem is, that substring isn't able to find the "x", so the xVærdi will not contain any elements. Or so I think.

the i is initialized as 1

```
while(isNumber(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i+1))) == true){
    xVærdi.add(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i+1)));
    i++;
}
```

And

```
System.out.println(xVærdi); //It doesn't contain anything. Output: []
```

The isNumber method:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String str)  {
        if((str.equals("-") && fortegn == false)){ 
            fortegn = true; //fortegn is a variable that allows the number to have it's minus with it
            return true;
        }
            else if (str.equals("+") || str.equals("*") || str.equals("/") || str.equals("=")){ 
                    return false;
        } else if((str.equals(".") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("0") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("1") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("2") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("3") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("4") && !fortegn) ||
                (str.equals("5") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("6") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("7") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("8") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("9") && !fortegn)){
            return true;
        } else 
            return false;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I have made a mini-program, as you can see below. However, the error does not occur in this example, so I am at a loss why it is happening. So I'm uploading a bigger part of my program. My output is 4, which is intended, and occurs.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Eksempel {

private static boolean fortegn = false;
private static int  i = 1;
static ArrayList xVærdi = new ArrayList();
private static String ligning = "y=3-2+4x-6";

    public static boolean erTal(String str)  {
        if((str.equals("-") && fortegn == false)){ //Variablen 'fortegn' sørger for at inkludere fortegnet af et tal, selvom det ikke er et tal. Dette sker kun en gang. 
            fortegn = true;
            return true;
        }
            else if (str.equals("+") || str.equals("*") || str.equals("/") || str.equals("=")){ 
                    return false;
        } else if((str.equals(".") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("0") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("1") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("2") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("3") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("4") && !fortegn) ||
                (str.equals("5") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("6") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("7") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("8") && !fortegn) || (str.equals("9") && !fortegn)){
            return true;
        } else //Kommer kun så langt hvis klienten har indtastet et bogstav andet end x. 
            return false;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(erTal(ligning.substring((ligning.indexOf("x")-i),(ligning.indexOf("x")-i+1))) == true){
                        xVærdi.add(ligning.substring((ligning.indexOf("x")-i),(ligning.indexOf("x")-i+1)));
                        i++;
                    }

    Collections.reverse(xVærdi);
    double xResult = Double.parseDouble(String.join("", xVærdi));
    System.out.println(xResult); //returns 4.0 which it should
}}
```

**The longer code that doesn't work:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Server{
private static String ligning = y=3x^3-2x^2+4x-6;
private static String replacedLigning;
private static int i = 1;
static ArrayList xVærdi = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList x2Værdi = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList x3Værdi = new ArrayList();

while(erTal(ligning.substring((ligning.indexOf("x^3")-i),
(ligning.indexOf("x^3")-i+1))) == true){

x3Værdi.add(ligning.substring((ligning.indexOf("x^3")-i),
(ligning.indexOf("x^3")-i+1)));
                        i++;
                    }

                    replacedLigning = ligning.replace("x^3","");
                    while(erTal(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x^2")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x^2")-i+1))) == true){
                        x2Værdi.add(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x^2")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x^2")-i+1)));
                        i++;
                    }

                   System.out.println(replacedLigning); //gives: y=3-2x^2+4x-6
                    replacedLigning = replacedLigning.replace("x^2","");

                    System.out.println(replacedLigning); //gives y=3-2+4x-6

                    i=1;
                    while(erTal(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i+1))) == true){
                        xVærdi.add(replacedLigning.substring((replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i),(replacedLigning.indexOf("x")-i+1)));
                        i++;
                    }

                    Collections.reverse(xVærdi);
                    Collections.reverse(x2Værdi);
                    Collections.reverse(x3Værdi);

                    System.out.println(xVærdi); **//Contains nothing: [] should contain [4]**
                    System.out.println(x2Værdi); **//Contains nothing: [] should contain [-2]**
                    System.out.println(x3Værdi); **//Contains [4, ., 6, -] should contain [3]**

                    double xResult = Double.parseDouble(String.join("", xVærdi)); //gets an error, because the arraylist is empty. 
                    double x2Result = Double.parseDouble(String.join("", x2Værdi));
                    double x3Result = Double.parseDouble(String.join("", x3Værdi));
```

Comment: No fortune-tellers over here. What is you code expected to do? What's the expected result ? What's the initial value of i ? What was substring unable to find that it should find ?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to inform you. I want xVærdi to contain the x value. In the example `y=3-2+4x-6` I want the xVærdi to store "4", since that's how many x'es there are. The initial value of xVærdi is none, and the problem is, that substring isn't able to find the "x", so the xVærdi will not contain any elements

Comment: Your isNumber method doesn't really do what you think it does. You don't check the single characters of your string, but allways the complete string. So instead of checking if the string startz with `-` you check if the string **is** `-` with `str.equals("-")`.  Therefor you will get true for `isNumber("-")` but false for `isNumber("-6")`

Comment: Now is probably a good time to read up on [`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) and regular expressions - `str.matches("[0-9.]")` is equivalent to all the equals checks you're doing in your last if statement.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I am pretty sure that I only check one character at a time, since I use the substring method like this:
`ligning.substring(a character, (a character) +1)`

Comment: How do you initialize `i` variable?

Comment: @talex i is initialized as 1

Comment: @Bassusour I was more viewing the method isolated. From a method isNumber(String str) you would normaly expect that you pass it a String and it returns true if is a valid number and false otherwise.

Comment: `String.charAt` is better if you just want to get one character (and `isNumber` should probably take a `char` instead of a `String`, although using `matches` as I suggested above won't work so well for that).

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Yea I see the name of the method is kinda misleading. I'm also kind of a beginner, so if you could come with an example on how to use your suggestions, I'd be thrilled.

Comment: Try to set `fortegn` to `false`.

Comment: [Your code seems to work fine for your given input.](http://ideone.com/XdS6Qs) Can you post [a short complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (including input and expected along with actual output) showing the problem you're having? Little disconnected sections of code tends to lead to confusion, misunderstandings, the question being unclear and an unreproducible issue.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, `4*x` is equivalent to `4x`, but your code treats them differently (somewhat similarly with `/`). This gets a bit more complex when you consider something like `4*5x`.

Comment: @Dukeling I have made a test-program i´where no error occurs. However, in my bigger program it happens

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I have updated the post. I hope you will help me, even thought there's a lot of code. It doesn't work in my bigger program, but in the small it does. I just feel like I'm doing it the excact same way

Comment: @Bassusour Then you should either debug your original program or slowly eliminate code from your original program until you manage to narrow down where the problem is (which you can then ask about, assuming how to fix it isn't obvious). We can't really help you if you can't give us code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Dukeling I have provided code that doesn't work. But good idea with the debugging

Comment: The longer code is still an incomplete code sample, but the only issue there seems to be that you didn't reset `fortegn` or `i`.

Comment: @Dukeling Holy shit I think that's that! Why didn't I think of resetting that too... Man i feel so dumb but thanks a lot!